# Python: subset a large series into a smaller series

Tags: pandas, series

I'm new to python and have a simple question but cannot find the answer anywhere. I have a data series with columns [dates, MKT, SMB, HML]. There are lots of rows - the dates go from 01.01.1926 to 01.10.2014.

I want to make a new series with the rows which extend from 01.01.2013 to 01.01.2014, how do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry you mean you have a dataframe with those columns and you just want to filter the rows to just those that satisfy that criteria? The following should work `df[(df['dates']>= '01/01/2013') & (df['dates']<= '01/01/2014)]`

Comment: My dataframe wasn't recognising my 'dates' index but I ended up solving it using df.loc[01012013:01012014]. Thank you for your help:)

Answer (score 2):

I had this data frame:

```
ff = pd.DataFrame(DataReader("F-F_Research_Data_Factors_daily", "famafrench")[0])
ff.columns = ['Mkt_rf', 'SMB', 'HML', 'rf']
```

I wanted to take just the rows with dates from 2014.07.14 to 2014.07.24. I did this using the loc index in pandas:

```
ff2 = ff.loc[20140714:20140724]
```